# command cron to run php file

Tags: php, cron

I trie to run a php file. The hoster allow me to write just a file name, I cant' change

> php -f /home/a4833978/

. I tried this but the file don't run
[image]

Comment: Will you clarify your problem? What do you expect to happen, and what is happening now? Do you receive any error messages?

Comment: the php file have to send an email every minute, but it don't happend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `* * * * *` instead of `1 1 * * *` if you want your script to run every minute. Your example would run once a day at 01:01.

In case you really want to run it once a day, check if your script works when executed directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably in your php file. If you do it in the way you did, all of your php includes will be messed up.

try to do it like this

```
cd /dir1/dir2/dir3/prod/update/ && php updater.php
```

also, make sure that files have executable tag on them.

Comment: That looks like a wild guess.